# Henkinization vs Skolemization

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am a novice in logic, and as I learn the basics of both constructions to, roughly speaking, witness quantifiers, one by constants (Henkin) and the other by Skolem functions, a couple of questions come to mind:

What significant distinctions exist between the two constructions? For example, are there situations when one is preferrable over the other?

Would you recommend a book which treats both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some evidence that Skolemization is instrumentally useful in proving the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem and Henkinization is instrumentally useful in proving compactness.

I strongly suspect, though, that if you really wanted to, you could use Skolemization nontrivially as a preprocessing step to construct a equisatisfiable $\exists$-free version of a theory $T$ as part of a compactness proof. (A Skolemized theory *is* also Henkinized, so the original proof would go through without changes.)

The usefulness of Henkinization in a proof of Löwenheim-Skolem seems limited, though.

---

I don't know whether the *usage* of these constructions differ significantly, but I can give you references that define both.

Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction* covers Henkinization on page 34 Definition 2.1.5

> We say that an $L$-theory $T$ has the witness property if whenever $\phi(v)$ is an $L$-formula with one free variable $v$, there is a constant symbol $c \in L$ such that $T \models (\exists v \mathop. \phi(v)) \to \phi(c)$.

It goes on to use this definition in a proof of the compactness theorem.

Skolem *functions* and Skolemization are defined on pages 45 and page 46.

The definition is quite similar, a theory has builtin Skolem functions if and only if for all wffs $\varphi$ with at least one free variable there exists a function $f$ such that $ T \models \forall \vec{x} \mathop. (\exists v \mathop. \varphi(v, \vec{x})) \to \varphi(f(\vec{x}), \vec{x})$.

Skolem functions are then used in a proof of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.

As for other books, Hodges' *A Shorter Model Theory* uses Hintikka sets to prove compactness on page 125. I don't really understand the proof, it appears to use existential witnesses in some manner though (and certainly contains the word *witness*).

Skolemization appears on page 71 in that book and appears immediately before a proof of the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.

Comment: Thank you. I checked Hodges' book, and it is an interesting proof. I wondered why he used Hintikka sets. It does not seem to make things any easier. Although after reading I came to realize that a Henkinized set of sentences is a Hintikka set, at least it appears so to me, morally.